# ImageResizer.net and S3Reader giving AWSSDK Version error

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, imageresizer

I've enabled the S3Reader plugin and set my bucket. I've added the s3reader plugin .dll to the project. Now any .net page (.aspx or even images) that I visit in my browser (localhost) throws the following error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK, Version=1.5.15.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f476d3089b52be3' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

i'm not sure where to go from here. my project is .net 4.5 and i'm using the latest awssdk for visual studio downloaded from the amazon site.

I've seen a couple of posts related to binding redirects but none seemed to work for me... any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [fixed in ImageResizer V3.3.3, released March 2 2013](http://imageresizing.net/releases/3-3-3).

Amazon changed their private key, completely breaking the ability to support both newer and older versions of the component simultaneously.